# Change the default WCF directory

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service which references a 3rd party DLL. That DLL looks for a settings file in the same directory as the DLL. However, WCF by default sets the current directory to "Inetpub" so of course the setting file can't be found.

I tried to set WCF to "Aspnet compatibility mode" but that didn't seem to work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: WCF never sets a default directory. What did you observe that led you to believe it did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you pass in the location of the settings files to the DLL? That's when the Aspnet compatibility mode comes to use, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114878/default-directory-in-a-wcf-service-that-is-hosted-in-iis6/1114893#1114893).

[But this might be what you're looking for.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751432.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't pass in the path. It always looks in the same directory as the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to access it from `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.